# Items pushing each other out the way

Tags: html, css

So I'm doing a horizontal website with individual sections which works fine but now that Ive added my menu i'm having trouble where its just ruining my whole content areas and background.
Ive tried using the z-index which has no effect whats so ever... and putting items before it just push it out the way too.

My CSS Nav Bar

```
    #Navigation
{
margin: 0px;
padding: 20px 0px 0px 700px;
font-family: 'american_captainregular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 55px;
float:left;
} 

#Navigation ul, #Navigation li
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}

#Navigation a:link, #Navigation a:visited
{
float: left;
line-height: 14px;
margin: 0 10px 4px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999;
}
#Navigation a:hover { color: #000; }
```

My CSS For the image

```
#HomeText{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-image: url(Images/HomeText.png);
float:left;
height:158px;
width:450px;
margin-left:461px;
margin-top:126px;

}
```

The HTML

```
<div id="Content">
<div class="Tabs TabOne" id="HomeTab">

<ul class="MyNav" id="Navigation">
<li><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#AboutTab" class="about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#PortfolioTab" class="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
</ul>
    <div id="HomeText"></div>
</div>
```

And just in case, the CSS for my Sections

```
    .Tabs{
    margin:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    float:left;
    width:3500px;

}

.TabOne{
background: url(Images/BG1.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

Ive never encountered this sort of issue with elements being pushed down the page as much as with this

http://jsfiddle.net/BoneStarr/AGfwn/

Comment: Can you have a jsfiddle for this. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: EDITED with Jfiddle at the bottom